# Как последовательно обойти элементы первого контейнера, а затем следующего с помощью JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Есть HTML документ:

```
<div class = "room">
    <div class = "red box"></div>
    <div class="orange box"></div>
    <div class="yellow box"></div>
    <div class="green box"></div>
    <div class="blue box"></div>
    <div class="violet box"></div>

</div>

<div class = line></div>

<div class="room">
    <div class = "red box"></div>
    <div class="orange box"></div>
    <div class="yellow box"></div>
    <div class="green box"></div>
    <div class="blue box"></div>
    <div class="violet box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS: 
    .box {background-color:red; height:30px; width:30px; position:absolute; margin:5px;}

Нужно расставить элементы внутри контейнера с классом "room" по кругу. Для этого я использую следующую функцию:

```
function drawCircle(selector, center, radius, angle, x, y)
{
    var total = $(selector).length;
    var alpha = Math.PI * 2 / total;
    $(selector).each(function(index)
    {
        var theta = alpha * index;
        var pointx  =  Math.floor(Math.cos( theta ) * radius);
        var pointy  = Math.floor(Math.sin( theta ) * radius );
        // Выводим координаты X и Y
        $(this).css('margin-left', pointx + x + 'px');
        $(this).css('margin-top', pointy  + y  + 'px');
    });
};
```

Но тут получается, что я сразу выбираю все подходящие элементы и они составляют одну общую окружность (для данного HTML в каждой "комнате" будет выстроена  полуокружность). 
Как последовательно расставить элементы в первой "комнате, а затем в последующих? 
P.S. Количество комнат может от 0 до N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте цикл, который для каждой "комнаты" будет вызывать функцию построения окружности. Например, так:

```
$(".room").each(function(){
  drawCircle($(this).children(".box"), center, radius, angle, x, y);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function drawCircle(elements, center, radius, angle, x, y) {
  var total = $(elements).length;
  var alpha = Math.PI * 2 / total;
  $(elements).each(function(index) {
    var theta = alpha * index;
    var pointx = Math.floor(Math.cos(theta) * radius);
    var pointy = Math.floor(Math.sin(theta) * radius);
    // Выводим координаты X и Y
    $(this).css('margin-left', pointx + x + 'px');
    $(this).css('margin-top', center + pointy + y + 'px');
  });
};

var marginTop = 50;
var marginLeft = 50;
var marginBottomFactor = 150;

$('.room').each(function(index) {
  var center = index * marginBottomFactor;
  var elements = $(this).find('.box');
  drawCircle(elements, center, 50, 10, marginLeft, marginTop);
});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="room">
  <div class="red box"></div>
  <div class="orange box"></div>
  <div class="yellow box"></div>
  <div class="green box"></div>
  <div class="blue box"></div>
  <div class="violet box"></div>
</div>

<div class="room">
  <div class="red box"></div>
  <div class="orange box"></div>
  <div class="yellow box"></div>
  <div class="green box"></div>
  <div class="blue box"></div>
  <div class="violet box"></div>
</div>

<div class="room">
  <div class="red box"></div>
  <div class="orange box"></div>
  <div class="yellow box"></div>
  <div class="green box"></div>
  <div class="blue box"></div>
  <div class="violet box"></div>
</div>
```